# How to combine two arrays by using a key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

There are plenty of answers around but I just can't seem to get this right, at all, the post seems big but it just seems. Here is what I have, and what I've tried.

```
Array
(
    [0] => image 1
    [1] => image 2
)

Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.14997300-1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
            [1] => 0.24654000-150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp
            [1] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509F.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55560
            [1] => 9425
        )

)
```

I've tried:

```
$instructions = $_POST['instructions'];
$image = $_FILES['instructions_image'];

$result = array();
foreach($instructions as $index => $key){
    $t = array();
    foreach($image as $img){
        $t[] = $img;
    }
    $result[$key] = $t;
}
```

And the results is:

```
Array
(
    [image 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.14997300 1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
                    [1] => 0.24654000 150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBAD5.tmp
                    [1] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBAE6.tmp
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55560
                    [1] => 9425
                )

        )

    [image 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.14997300 1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
                    [1] => 0.24654000 150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBAD5.tmp
                    [1] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBAE6.tmp
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55560
                    [1] => 9425
                )

        )

)
```

I'm unsure why the results have 2 of the same in both indexes, but I was also wanting to know how we could keep the array key names provided by the $_FILES, ex: name, type, tmp_name, error and size.

Here is what I was expecting(I included additional information like the key names that I didn't provide nor did with my code, sorry about that, been at it for 12 hours non stop but just any explanation to set me on the right path would help me tremendously):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => image 1,
            [image_data] => Array (
                [name] => 0.14997300 1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 55560
            )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => image 2,
            [image_data] => Array (
                [name] => 0.24654000 150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 9425
            )

        )

)
```

Comment: Please share your expected result.

Comment: To keep the key names, check your inner `foreach()` loop. You are skipping index of that array and building new array with numeric indices through `[]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @insider

Comment: @John https://eval.in/853017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful. Here we are using simple `foreach` loop `array_keys`, `array_combine` and `array_column`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/853101)

```
$result=array();
foreach($images as $key => $image)
{
    $result[]=array(
        "text"=>$image,
        "image_data"=>array_combine(
                array_keys($instructions),
                array_column($instructions,$key))
    );
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: As helpful as it gets, I went to read up on array_column, and to understand why I was getting different results even though I wrote the exact same code you shared, figured out you simply mixed up the instructions and images variable names haha! It's perfect, thank you for guiding me in the right direction Sahil.

Comment: @SahilGulati your script is loosing the 'image_data' sub items keys (-;

Comment: @John Glad to help you my friend... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a custom script which combines these arrays by your logic. For this task you can use this array functions: [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Example:

```
<?php
$a1 = ['image 1', 'image 2'];
$a2 = [
    'name' => ['0.14997300-1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg', '0.24654000-150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg'],
    'type' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg'],
    'tmp_name' => ['C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp', 'C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509F.tmp'],
    'error' => [0, 0],
    'size' => [55560, 9425]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = [
        'text' => $v,
        'image_data' => array_combine(array_keys($a2), array_column($a2, $k))
    ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you
    $res=array(0 => 'image 1',1 => 'image 2');

```
            $valu=array('name' => array(0=> '0.14997300-1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg',1 => '0.24654000-150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg'
                    ),'type' => array( 0 => 'image/jpeg',1 => 'image/jpeg'), 'tmp_name'=> array(0 => 'C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp',1 => 'C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509F.tmp'),'error' => array(0 => 0,1 => 0),'size' => array(0 => 55560, 1 => 9425)
                    );

            $newarr=array();
            foreach($res as $key=>$val)
            {
                $newarr[$key]['text']=$val;
                $newarr[$key]['image_data']=array('name'=>$valu['name'][$key],'type'=>$valu['type'][$key],'tmp_name'=>$valu['tmp_name'][$key],'error'=>$valu['error'][$key],'size'=>$valu['size'][$key]);
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fileData = array(
    'name' => ['0.14997300-1503597010599f11d2249df30.jpg','0.24654000-150113339659797a543c31f24.jpg'],
    'type' => ['image/jpeg','image/jpeg'],
    'tmp_name' => ['C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509E.tmp','C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Temp\php509F.tmp'],
    'error' => [0,0],
    'size' => [55560,9425]);

$someArr = array('image 1','image 2');
$fileData['somedata'] = $someArr;


function reFileData($fileData) { 
    $arr = array();
    $keys = array_keys($fileData);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($fileData['name']); $i++) {
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $arr[$i][$key] = $fileData[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

print_r(reFileData($fileData));
```